# how to import notes id file in mail database using lotusscript

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, lotusscript

Is there a way to programmatically import a user's notes id into their mail database using lotusscript? I'm trying to automate the manual process of Notes ID management for secure mail feature in IBM Domino Security Preferences.

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Maybe ID Vault could help you better than importing ID ? If not response is yes lotuscript allow you to import ID (for exemple as attachment) but you have to write a program

Answer (score 0):

Usually the ID file is on the local user drive. So you cannot access it centrally. If it is on a network drive, e.g. within the user sub-directory, then of course you'll be able to get and process it.

So, two scenarios:

On network drive:
 - go over all drives, search the ids and attach it to the corresponding mailbox. However, it might be complicated to determine which network drive belong to which Domino user. Also one user might have multiple id files. This could become very complicated!

On local drive:
 - you might want to perform the actions quite easy by running a LotusScript by the user, e.g. by sending a button that the user has to press. When the user is doing it, it is clear which id file is currently in use and the code will have access to it (because the user is currently using it). However, this solution relies on the user ability to press the button.